# Mysqli join query return wrong COUNT?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, group-by, count

I'm new in php. I'm having problem with my join query.I want count from join query for pagination but count return only 1.I don't get any idea to how i fix this.can anyone help me to how i get count properly in my join query.

my join query is below :-

```
SELECT COUNT(l.id) as total
     , l.*
     , ls.lead_id
     , ls.lead_status
     , ls.date 
  from lead_status as ls 
  join leads as l 
    on l.id = ls.lead_id 
   and l.status = ls.lead_status 
WHERE is_deleted = 0 
   and ls.lead_status = 1 
   and l.status = 1 
 group 
    by id 
 order 
    by id 
 LIMIT 0, 20
```

if i run this query so i return result like this ....

[image]

and i run query without GROUP by l.id so i get count perfect but i got only one record from database.

see

[image]

Relation between leads and lead_status is...in leads table id and lead_status table lead_id.And i want to count leads tables id.

I want total records with row count.Count for pagination and records for show on my view page.

i want join query result like below image with total row count and get all data.

[image]

Comment: group  by id  --> l.id and

Comment: Hello, can you post some example data and the expected result?

Comment: @Nami please share table details.. too

Comment: plz mention relation between lead_status & lead tables. Here which table rows you want to count?

Comment: The result is correct as per query...

Comment: You need to join lead_status by keeping leads as main table

Comment: As before, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: that's okay @Strawberry because this project is on local server and is for my learning and i can't upload this project on any live server.that's why i provide images.

Comment: We still need some data. With the images we can not see why your result would be wrong.

Comment: Hello @Nami, will you please tell what you actually want as result, I mean total number of leads?, or number of leads generated by specific user or on specific date?

Comment: which type of example or data i want to provide ? can u tell me? @Philipp

Comment: Some rows from both tables. The result which you want to have, for those rows.

Comment: i add on my question. or anything you want to know or something like example then tell me. @RaviGaudani

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're not going to read the advice provided, we can't really help.

Comment: i read advice and understand it.@Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want total number of leads for pagination, run following query

```
SELECT l.*, ls.lead_id, ls.lead_status, ls.date 
FROM leads as l JOIN lead_status as ls ON l.id = ls.lead_id
WHERE l.is_deleted = 0
and l.status = 1
and ls.lead_status = 1
```

this query returns all the leads from your table, now count the number of record using php's mysqli_num_rows(), or sizeof() function.

Comment: i got error in this query.

Comment: it's because you didn't provide both table, will you please add the error here.

Comment: i got error like this `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as total_lead
FROM leads as l JOIN lead_status as ls ON l.id = ls.lead_id
W' at line 1`

Comment: Update COUNT(l.*) to COUNT(l.id) or COUNT(*)

Comment: If this query returns the result as you want, please accept my answer

Comment: with your query i return only count and not return any other records. wait i add one example in my question so you can help me more and understand it what i really want. @Ravi Gaudani

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187985/discussion-between-ravi-gaudani-and-nami).

Answer (score -2):

Problem with `id`, you can join table and may be there is another table have `id` column.

So please define that from which id you have to group the result.

Change in group statement and order by like `l.id` or `ls.id`.

Comment: i try but problem is same you can see on my first image. @Madhuri Patel

Comment: @Nami check where condition

Comment: Also change in  `order` condition

Comment: please show database query image and tell me how i get all record with correct count. @MadhuriPatel

Answer (score -2):

You are using Group By clause, so it will count the grouped ids. As the id is an unique key, the 1 total will be the result for every row.